# Matrix Multiplication Simplification not giving same results in code

Tags: matlab, precision, floating-accuracy

I want to evaluate the expression x<sup>T</sup>Ax -2y<sup>T</sup>Ax+y<sup>T</sup>Ay in Matlab.

If my calculations are correct, this should be equivalent to solving(x-y)<sup>T</sup>A(x-y)

My main problem right now is that I am not getting the same results from the above two expressions. I'm wondering if it's a precision error or a conceptual error.

I tried a very simple example with some random values to check my math was right. The mini example I used is as follows

```
A = [1,2,0;2,1,2;0,2,1];

x = [1;2;3];

y = [4;4;4];
```

```
(transpose(x)*A*x)-(2*transpose(y)*A*x)+(transpose(y)*A*(y))
transpose(x-y)*A*(x-y)
```

Both give 46.

I then tried a more realistic example of values for what I'm doing and it failed. For example

```
A = [2.66666666666667,-0.333333333333333,0,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,0,0,0,0;
-0.333333333333333,2.66666666666667,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,0,0,0;
0,-0.333333333333333,2.66666666666667,0,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,0,0,0;
-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,0,2.66666666666667,-0.333333333333333,0,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,0;
-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,2.66666666666667,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333   -0.333333333333333;
0,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,0,-0.333333333333333,2.66666666666667,0,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333;
0,0,0,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,0,2.66666666666667,-0.333333333333333,0;
0,0,0,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,2.66666666666667,-0.333333333333333;
0,0,0,0,-0.333333333333333,-0.333333333333333,0,-0.333333333333333,2.66666666666667];


x =[1.21585420370805;
1.00388159497757e-16;
-0.405284734569351;
1.36809776609658e-16;
-1.04796659533634e-17;
-7.52459042423650e-17;
-0.607927101854027;
-8.49163704356314e-17;
0.303963550927013];

v =[0.0319067068305797,0.00786616506360615,0.0709811622828447,0.0719615328671117;
1.26150800194897e-17,5.77584497721720e-18,7.89740111567879e-18,7.14396333930938e-18;
-0.158358815125228,-0.876275686098803,0.0539216716399594,0.0450616819309899;
7.90937837037453e-18,3.24196519177793e-18,3.99402664932776e-18,4.17486202509670e-18;
5.35533279761622e-18,-8.91723780863019e-19,-1.56128480212603e-18,1.84423677629470e-19;
-2.18478057810330e-17,-6.63779320738873e-18,-3.21099714760257e-18,-3.93612240449303e-18;
-0.0213963226092681,-0.0168256143048771,-0.0175695110350900,-0.0128155908603601;
-4.06029341772399e-18,-5.65705978843172e-18,-1.80182480882056e-18,-1.59281757789645e-18;
0.221482525259710,-0.0576644539359728,0.0163934384910353,0.0197432976432437];

u = [1.37058079022968;
1.79302486419321;
69.4330887239959;
-52.3949662214410];

y = v*u;
```

Gives 0 for the first expression and 7.1387e-28 for the second. Is this a precision error thing? Which version is better/ more accurate to use and why? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked your simplification, but floating-point math in general is inexact. Even doing the same operations in a different order can give you different results. With the deviations you are seeing I would believe they could reasonably come from inexactness in floating-point math and it is up to you to decide whether the deviations are acceptable for your purpose.
To determine which version is more accurate you would have to compute reference values to compare to, which might prove difficult.